# Getting XamlParseException when calling XamlReader.Load(xmlReader)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

I am getting XamlParseException when calling XamlReader.Load() in button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) the code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using HTMLConverter;
using System.Windows.Markup;


namespace StackoverflowTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=" + @".\SQLEXPRE" +
                                    ";Initial Catalog=Hukuk;" +
                                    "Integrated Security=True;" +
                                    "User ID=;" +
                                    "Password=;");

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening SQL Server connection\n" + ex.Message);
                //Close();
            }

        }

        public static FlowDocument SetRTF(string xamlString)
        {
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
            System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand commProc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Content from Document where ID=3219", MainWindow.conn);
            string str;
            FlowDocumentReader fdocr = new FlowDocumentReader();
            SqlDataReader dr = commProc.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    byte[] bt = (byte[])dr["Content"];
                    str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bt);
                    str = HTMLConverter.HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(str, true);
                    fdocr.Document = MainWindow.SetRTF(str);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occured while trying to view document\n" + ex.Message);
            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately a cannot post the xamlstring I'm trying to pass because it is too big..Is there any other way to show it to you?

And the exception details are here:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message='Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Documents.TableRowGroupCollection' threw an exception.' Line number '1' and line position '28143'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=28143
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, ParserContext parserContext)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(XmlReader reader, ParserContext parserContext, XamlParseMode parseMode)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(XmlReader reader)
       at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.SetRTF(String xamlString) in C:\Documents and Settings\nosirovkh\Рабочий стол\посл\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 69
  InnerException: System.ArgumentNullException
       Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
       Source=PresentationFramework
       ParamName=item
       StackTrace:
            at MS.Internal.Documents.TableTextElementCollectionInternal`2.Add(TElementType item)
            at MS.Internal.Documents.ContentElementCollection`2.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
            at System.Windows.Documents.TableRowGroupCollection.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
            at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.AddToCollection(Object instance, Object item)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.Add(Object collection, XamlType collectionType, Object value, XamlType valueXamlType)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any exception for me. Either it's caused by something in your `…`, or something completely different. Try to create a simple application that actually reproduces the issues and post it here.

Comment: @svick: I agree, creating a simple repro application is the way to go here.  I don't want to see code that generates an error that mentions `line position 41430`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add `null` into a `TableRowGroupCollection`. If you format the XAML with proper indentation and line breaks instead of all on one line (as I assume it is), you should be able to find the specific line that has the problem. If you post the XAML at that point, we should be able to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @svick I've created a simple application which reproduces the issue.@kendfrey The xamlstring value is too big to post it here, can I e-mail it to you or somehow else?

Comment: @kendfrey could you please tell me in details what you mean by saying "format the XAML with proper indentation and line breaks" ?

Comment: I meant simple application that we can use to reproduce the problem. We don't have your database, so don't use that. And if the XAML is too big, then try to simplify it.

Comment: Going by the exception detail you gave, it appears that your XAML is all on one line. You should open it in your favourite text editor (Notepad++ and Visual Studio work well) and ensure that each tag is on its own line, and that child tags are indented from their parent. If the XAML file is less than 1 MB, you may email it to me so I can take a look at it. (Contact me through my website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your XAML is probably generated by some program, which is the source of the problem.

Here is the problem:

```
<Table>
  <TableColumn Width="331"/>
  <TableColumn Width="48"/>
  <TableColumn Width="48"/>
  <TableColumn Width="48"/>
  <TableColumn Width="48"/>
  <TableColumn Width="44"/>
  <TableColumn Width="52"/>
  ...
</Table>
```

And here is the correct code:

```
<Table>
  <Table.Columns>
    <TableColumn Width="331"/>
    <TableColumn Width="48"/>
    <TableColumn Width="48"/>
    <TableColumn Width="48"/>
    <TableColumn Width="48"/>
    <TableColumn Width="44"/>
    <TableColumn Width="52"/>
  </Table.Columns>
  ...
</Table>
```

There are 6 tables where this occurs.

I don't know what generated this XAML, but this seems like a bad bug. You will either need it to be fixed or fix the XAML file yourself, either by writing a small program to find that kind of thing, or manually with (preferably) Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying to write a small program to add  `<Table.Columns>` and `</Table.Columns>` where it's necessary. I'll post the results as soon as I'm finished.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, you helped me to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when launch a WPF application with the following xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="XXX.Wpf.IV.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="IV" WindowState="Normal" Height="1024" Width="1280">

<Grid>
    <local:IVView x:Name="_ivView"/> 
</Grid>

</Window>
```

Turns out the reason that caused "XmalParseException add to collection..." was that my IVView class should have been UserControl but I created it as an extension of Window. I am suspecting that we have having similar issues.